# Action after loginByCookie()

Tags: yii2

In my app, I'm using session to store some user's data (e.g. name, role). I'm using default `User` class on `common/models` from yii2 and I'm getting the data I need by user id.
The problem is that the data I stored in session are lost if user resume their previous session without entering password (using remember me option). To solve this, I tried to modify and put the codes for saving user's data inside `validateAuthKey()` method in `User` since it's called when yii2 checking for authkey to resume session. As in:

```
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    $user = Member::findOne(['account_id' => Yii::$app->user->id]);

    // Save on session
    Yii::$app->session->set('name', $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name);
    Yii::$app->session->set('position', $user->position);
    // .. other data

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I use the id of logged user to find `Member`. But by doing this, I got "Trying to get property of non-object" exception from `Yii::$app->user->id`. I can only get the id after the login process is completed. After prying around, I found that `loginByCookie()` from `User` in `vendor\yiisoft\yii2\Web` is used to log in. Is there any way to save user's data without tampering codes on vendor? Maybe some kind of event after `loginByCookie()` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own User model extends \yii\web\User

   ```
   namespace frontend\components;
   class User extends \yii\web\User
   {
       protected function afterLogin($identity, $cookieBased, $duration)
       {
           ...Do something here...
           parent::afterLogin($identity, $cookieBased, $duration);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Modify the config (main.php).

   ```
   'components' => [
       'user' => [
           'class' => 'frontend\components\User',
           'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
           ...
       ]
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in **common/config/bootstrap.php**

The `EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN` will be called even if the user is logged in by cookie.

```
    use yii\web\User;
    use yii\base\Event;

        Event::on(User::className(), User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, function() {

           $user = Member::findOne(['account_id' => Yii::$app->user->id]);

            // Save on session
           Yii::$app->session->set('name', $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name);
           Yii::$app->session->set('position', $user->position);

        });
```